# Como no repetir codigo en vba excel (con una conexion a base de datos access)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, microsoft-office

tengo una conexion que trae informacion de una base de datos pero cada vez que tengo que consultar algo tengo que volver a copiar y pegar todo, hay alguna forma de abrir la conexion y cerrarla con una "function" o otro metodo

*esta parte se repite en todo*

```
'Nombre de la base de datos que debe estar ubicada en la misma carpeta que este excel
MiBase = "Base.accdb"

Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
MiConexion = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & MiBase

With Conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Open MiConexion
End With
```

*lo unico que varia*

```
 name = LCase(Environ("UserName"))

'seleccion de la base de datos
Query = "SELECT * FROM admin"

Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Rs.CursorLocation = adUseServer
Rs.Open Source:=Query, _
ActiveConnection:=Conn
admin = LCase(Rs![username])
```

*y vuelve a repetirse codigo*

```
'Cerrar la conexión
Rs.Close
Conn.Close
Set Rs = Nothing
Set Conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

quisiera no repetir tanto y gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

se tiene que crear una private function como se ve acontinuacion y llamarla desde el codigo que se necesita *recomiendo ponerlo dentro del mismo modulo que el codigo necesario

```
private function entrada()
  'Nombre de la base de datos que debe estar ubicada en la misma carpeta que este excel
   MiBase = "Base.accdb"

   Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
   MiConexion = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & MiBase

   With Conn
   .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
   .Open MiConexion
   End With
End Function
```

se declara otra como salida para cerrar la conexion

```
    private function salida()
   'Cerrar la conexión
    Rs.Close
    Conn.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
    Set Conn = Nothing
    end function
```

y luego un SUB para ejecutar todo el codigo junto

```
sub Completo()

entrada

name = LCase(Environ("UserName"))

'seleccion de la base de datos
Query = "SELECT * FROM admin"

Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Rs.CursorLocation = adUseServer
Rs.Open Source:=Query, _
ActiveConnection:=Conn
admin = LCase(Rs![username])

salida

end sub
```

y con esto puedes tener un codigo dinamico y poco repetitivo.